# Unexpected end of input when created angular module

Tags: angularjs

I have problem in angularJS. when I create Myapp

```
var Myapp = angular.module('Myapp', []);
```

and I have error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`
I don't forget missing ']' or '}',';' and anything

Comment: Your code works. So we need more code to find your problem...

Comment: can you provide more code. your code snippet looks fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Google Chrome, press F12 and debug the error in the console to see the line of code you are getting the error and have more information about it.

Comment: This shouldn't be given as an "answer". An answer solves the original question, and this doesn't (in large part because the question lacks critical information). Use the comments section instead.

Comment: I know, but as I have not reached 50 reputation score I can't add comments to the original question, and I wanted to write this answer to Vĩ Lương. Sorry about that! ;)